# to display a vector

Tags: r

```
> a=c(1,2,3,4)  
> a      
[1] 1 2 3 4  
> typeof(a)  
[1] "double"  
> mode(a)  
[1] "numeric"  
> attributes(a)  
NULL 
> str(a)  
num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
```

is there something to make a  display  it  vector?

Comment: @DanielFischer: owner retagged `r`.

Comment: @yhyrcanus Nope.  `str()` is a function returning a summary of an object.

Comment: More like structure than a summary. I think summary is reserved for the same name function.

Comment: @PengPeng What do you mean "make a display it vector"? Can you type exactly what you would like to see? Do you want it to say "vector"?

Comment: yes ,i want R to say "vector"  as   > g <- function(x)x  
> class(g)   
[1] "function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `is.vector()`?  This tests whether an object is a vector:

```
is.vector(a)
[1] TRUE
```

---

As a counter-example:

```
g <- function(x)x

is.vector(g)
[1] FALSE

class(g)
[1] "function"
```

Comment: if i don't know a is verctor,how can i use is.vector()?

Comment: @PengPeng `is.vector` tests whether an object is a vector or not. See my edited answer.